# Running an INSERT statement automatically using Command Line

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file, command-line

I have a statement that I run from MySQL Workbench that works just the way I want it.

```
INSERT INTO queuelist(songID)
select ID from songlist where filename LIKE CONCAT('%', substring(curdate(), 6,5) ,'%') order by filename
```

I now want to automate the process using Windows Scheduler and a batch file.  I am fairly new to this process and not very familiar with how the command line works. I started like this:

```
mysql -u username -pMyPassword -D MyDatabase < code.sql
```

Where code.sql contains the query that I posted above -- When I run this, I get completely different results from when I run it in Workbench.  Do I need to format it differently?

Thanks
Chuck

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put that insert statement into a MySQL [event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)? Then the DB engine will run it for you automatically.

```
delimiter //
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS your_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
STARTS  '2014-08-19 12:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
    INSERT INTO queuelist(songID)
    select ID 
    from songlist
    where filename LIKE CONCAT('%', substring(curdate(), 6,5) ,'%') 
    order by filename
//
```

You need to adjust the times when it should run in the code above

Comment: This will work, I believe, but forgive me, Do I need to execute this every day, or once I do it the first time, it will be in my server for good?

Comment: Execute it once. In the definition you can specify how often this is run for instance `EVERY 1 DAY`. And you can define the start of it. Using `2014-08-19 12:00:00` will start executing today at `12` and continue every day at `12`

Comment: First things first -- Error 1044 Access denied for user root .. I beleive that's the only user in the server with all rights .. I've never touched it out of the box .. other then setting the password

Comment: It's weird..still able to run other queries in workbench with no access errors .. just not that one

Comment: Try reconnecting in the MySQL Workbench. That is the tool you are using, right?

Comment: Nevermind -- I ran it directly from the server instead of my remote computer -- Fingers crossed -- Thanks for the help!